# Match string with prefix and at least one comma (,)

Tags: regex

Trying to match a comma seperated list of values.
I want to check that a comma ',' occurs at least once and string contains a certain prefix

ie
tel_local: 123456, tel_national: 123456

is valid but:
tel_local: 123456 is not as no comma

Currently using

```
^(tel_local:)|(tel_national:),+$
```

but it matches tel_local: 123456

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
^(\w+: \d+)(?:, (\w+: \d+))*$
```

Answer (score 0):

To do ***exactly*** what you ask, use:

```
^tel_(?:local|national):(?=.*?,)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yB4uM9/2)

---

First, your main problem was the alternation.  Think about if you have a conditional `(A=B OR A=C) AND Z=5`. The parenthesis are necessary in order for the order of evaluating to remain correct, same with the alternation (`(?:local|national)`) in your expression.

---

Then, since you didn't specify *what* had to come after `tel_local` or `tel_national` (one would assume a space and digits) asides from that it **needed** a comma, I used a lookahead assertion. `(?=.*?,)` will look ahead 0+ characters and check for a `,`.  If no comma is found, the assertion will fail and your match will end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=[^,]*,)((?:tel_local|tel_national): *\d+,? *)+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rL2eJ2/2)

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the kleene plus ("+") in a regular expression to state that some term should feature at least one or more times

therefore, if you want to specify a string to match should contain at least one comma something like ",+" should do